# Converting DATE 2012-09-16 to php date("l F jS") (PHP/mySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a dates in mySQL stored in format 2012-09-16 as DATE format and I want to output and convert the date into the format  `date("l F jS")`.

I am using a while loop to query my table which SELECTS the date:

```
while($rowWeek=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultWeek)){
    echo date("l F jS", $rowWeek[dt]); 
}
```

The code above outputs: `Wednesday December 31st`. For each and every day which tells me that `date()` doesn't like the format being used from `$rowWeek[dt]`

when it should loop through 7 days of the current week.

```
echo $rowWeek[dt];
```

outputs the correct dates:

```
2012-09-16
2012-09-17
2012-09-18
2012-09-19
2012-09-20
2012-09-21
2012-09-22
```

How do I convert the SELECTED date format of 2012-09-16  and convert it to the more pleasant format of `date("l F jS")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `strtotime()`:

```
echo date("l F jS", strtotime($rowWeek['dt']));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do the formatting in MySQL, you can do this:

```
SELECT dateformat("%W %M %D", mydate)
```

Just FYI, I'll get more value if you find this answer helpful than if I earn any points for it.  What am I going to do, put my SO score on my resume??

Good luck.